# Dialyzer says function will never be called, even though it is

Tags: erlang, elixir, dialyzer

I am using the elixir_talk library. After connecting I want to call a private function once connected to beanstalkd. I just added typespecs and ran Dialyzer (via dialyxir). I get the errors:

```
my_module.ex:3: The specification for 'Elixir.MyModule':f/0 states that the function might also return 'ok' | {'error',_} but the inferred return is none()
my_module.ex:4: Function f/0 has no local return
my_module.ex:14: Function g/1 will never be called
```

The minimal example I could find that produces this is

```
defmodule MyModule do
  @spec f() :: :ok | {:error, term}
  def f() do
    case ElixirTalk.connect('127.0.0.1', 11300) do
      {:ok, conn} ->
        g(conn)
      {:error, err} ->
        {:error, err}
    end
  end

  @spec g(pid) :: :ok
  defp g(pid) do
    :ok
  end
end
```

If I replace the call to `ElixirTalk.connect` with a call to `spawn` instead, Dialyzer no longer reports any problems.

```
defmodule MyModule do
  @spec f() :: :ok
  def f() do
    x = spawn fn -> :done end
    g(x)
  end

  @spec g(pid) :: :ok
  defp g(pid) do
    :ok
  end
end
```

Does anyone know why Dialyzer is getting confused here?

Comment: Do you get the same result if you pass a timeout value as the third argument to `ElixirTalk.connect`?

Comment: @legoscia that resolved it! Why did that cause this issue?

Comment: Looking at [the source](https://github.com/jsvisa/elixir_talk/blob/master/lib/elixir_talk.ex#L16), the type spec says that the third argument is always an integer, even though the default value is the atom `infinity`. Thus, a call to `ElixirTalk.connect` with infinite timeout would be against the type spec. In Erlang you'd fix this by specifying the type as `timeout()` instead, which allows both integers and `infinity`; not sure how that translates to Elixir.

Comment: Nice! This should also be manifesting as a warning for `ElixirTalk.connect/2` itself, but since it is probably in the PLT it is not shown?

Comment: Hi @legoscia--maybe you should extract your comment as an answer so it's obviously visible to everyone. :)

Comment: What are the return values of `ElixirTalk.connect`?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source, the type spec says that the third argument is always an integer, even though the default value is the atom infinity. Thus, a call to ElixirTalk.connect with infinite timeout would be against the type spec. In Erlang you'd fix this by specifying the type as timeout() instead, which allows both integers and infinity; not sure how that translates to Elixir. – legoscia May 16 '16 at 15:56

Comment: `type timeout :: integer | :infinity`